# Android - Nesting Fragments No View Found

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have three Fragments and they are arranged as shown below:

"Frag A and Frag C is not connected, but Frag B and C are. The each fragment contains 1 listview so every time I triggered an event it will go to the next fragment."

> Fragment A ---> (Inside Frag `A`)Fragment B  --->  (Inside Frag `B`)Fragment C

- Fragment A(main.xml)
- Fragment B(R.id.contentFragment)
- Fragment C(R.id.contentFragment)

I can display Fragment A and Fragment B and is okay, *but* if I call Fragment C from `B`I got `"No view found in contentFragment=0x7f040039"`.

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"  
                android:background="@color/white" 
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout"    
                >

            <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            >
            </ListView>

    <FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/contentFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1" >
     </FrameLayout>


    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

FragmentA.java

**Inside Fragment A to open Fragment B**

```
 Fragment fragment1 = new FragmentB();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment1, fragMainGroups );
        transaction.addToBackStack(fragMainGroups);
        transaction.commit();
```

**FragmentB.java**

**Inside Fragment B to open Fragment C**

```
     String fragGroups = "groups";

    Fragment fragment1 = new FragmentC();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment1, fragGroups );
    transaction.addToBackStack(fragGroups);
    transaction.commit();
```

**FragmentC.java**

**Inside Fragment C**

```
   public class FragmentItems extends ListFragment{

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            }

            public void onCreate(Bundle e)
            {
                super.onCreate(e);
            }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.load_items_activity, container, false);

                    return rootView;
                }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
07-25 18:10:20.388: E/FragmentManager(24703): No view found for id 0x7f040039 (com.jinisys.restoplusordering:id/contentFragment) for fragment FragmentItems{4156f480 #0 id=0x7f040039 groups}
07-25 18:10:20.388: E/FragmentManager(24703): Activity state:

07-25 18:10:20.388: E/FragmentManager(24703): No view found for id 0x7f040039 (com.jinisys.restoplusordering:id/contentFragment) for fragment FragmentItems{4156f480 #0 id=0x7f040039 groups}
07-25 18:10:20.388: E/FragmentManager(24703): Activity state:
07-25 18:10:20.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24703): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 18:10:20.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24703): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f040039 (com.jinisys.restoplusordering:id/contentFragment) for fragment FragmentItems{4156f480 #0 id=0x7f040039 groups}
07-25 18:10:20.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24703):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
07-25 18:10:20.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24703):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
07-25 18:10:20.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24703):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-25 18:10:20.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24703):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
07-25 18:10:20.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24703):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
07-25 18:10:20.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24703):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
```

Answer (score 0):

As your error states you are looking for a view with id `contentFragmentTtems` inside Fragment B, main view for which is `contentFragment` and not the whole `main.xml`. So if you want to add new fragment you should do it also from Fragment A.

Comment: Please assume that `contentFragmentTtems ` is deleted I don't need this sir. Please see updated code. I want to replace what `contentFragment` contains in Fragment C as what I did in Fragment A. I use only `main.xml` to display the nested fragments.

Comment: Well if you want to replace your Fragment B with Fragment C, then yes you have to replace `contentFragment`, but as I said earlier you have to do this from Fragment A and not from Fragment B.

Comment: I am sure if I understood what you mean with this sir, `to do this from Fragment A and not from Fragment B`. `Frag A` and `Frag C` is not connected sir, but `Frag B` and `C` are. The each fragment contains 1 listview so every time trigger an event it will go to the next fragment.

Comment: okay, so as I see you tried to replace `contentFragmentTtems` to `contentFragment` and it didn't helped?

Comment: It didn't help, so I decided to just use `contentFragment ` as one view in the nesting process. Frag A-uses main.xml; Frag `B` and `C` uses `R.id.contentFragment ` but C can't find any view from `contentFragment `

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"  
                android:background="@color/white" 
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout"    
                >

            <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            >
            </ListView>

    <FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/contentFragmentb"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1" >
     </FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/contentFragmentc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1" >
     </FrameLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

This should work.